# Suggested edits: Better visual indication of whether edit is to a question or an answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, information-display

Could we please have a clearer visual indication of whether the suggested edit is an edit to a question or an answer?  Currently the only way I distinguish between the two is to look for the (very light gray) text *asked* or *answered* next to original poster's name.

[image: suggested edit on question]

[image: suggested edit on answer]

Comment: With the recent [review queue overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues), the UI now gives a clear visual indication, making this feature request obsolete: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoX7Y.png

Answer (score 5):

I was just about to suggest the same, when I found this question. For now just the question title is being displayed:

[image]

I suggest that the question title is prefixed with "Answer to:" if the edit has been suggested to an answer of the displayed question:

> ### Answer to: Drupal 7 - How to load a template file from a module?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't think that this will be fixed in the short term, I created a small [user script](https://stackapps.com/q/8695) to work around this issue.

The script detects whether a post is a question or an answer, and adds this information as a new heading, similar to the other review queues. It also highlights whether a question is closed, as I tend to overlook this information too.

For example, [this review on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26462886) is rendered as:
[image: Suggested edit review with added "Answer" heading]

I tested with latest Firefox and Chrome, using the Tampermonkey browser extension.

Feel free to propose improvements or report bugs at the linked Stack Apps post.

Comment: @JanWichelmann Nice little script, does exactly what it promises! (Works fine with greasemonkey, too) Maybe you could post it on https://stackapps.com/ to increase visibility?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good idea, I did not think of that! Looks like the right place to post this.

Comment: As suggested, I have now posted this to Stack Apps :)