# Differentiate between questions and answers in the suggested edit queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested edits: Better visual indication of whether edit is to a question or an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79794/suggested-edits-better-visual-indication-of-whether-edit-is-to-a-question-or-an)

I've now accidentally rejected a few edits because they edited the code, and code in questions shouldn't be edited by others since it might remove the whole problem that the question is about.  BUT on answers, it's fine to edit the code a little for various reasons.

The problem I've found is that there doesn't seem to be a way to differentiate whether you're dealing with a question or an answer, when looking at the suggested edit page, so if I don't go into the post, I can make a bad decision on which one it is, and find out later I'm wrong (when it's too late to change my vote).

Could we please have some differentiation between questions and answers on the suggested edit page?

Comment: Sorry, I realized this isn't *strictly* a duplicate, although the fact that you didn't know where to look is probably a sign that it should be made much more clear.

Comment: @tim, I agree that it's a dupe, and voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to differentiate, it's just fairly subtle. The user box at the bottom of the suggestion says "answered {date stamp}" if the post is an answer, and "asked {date stamp}" if the post is a question:

[image: Screenshot of the user boxes]

Comment: Thanks.  Now I know where to look.