# Make post type more obvious in suggested edits queue

Tags: feature-request, review, design, suggested-edits

I just got full editing privileges on SO, and started reviewing edits. When checking out my edit history in order to find out how others have decided in some particular cases, I noticed that one post which I [reviewed as "Edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26312735) has been deleted a few minutes later.

It took me quite some time to realize that the edited post, which looked like a valid question, has been posted as an *answer* (and thus is obviously NAA). Unfortunately, this information is only shown in the bottom left corner, with low contrast:

[image: Suggested edit queue, "answered ... ago" in bottom left corner highlighted]

After reviewing X questions, this one just slipped through. I obviously learned my lesson, but it might still help preventing similar mistakes: **Could you move the post type information to a more obvious location?**

One could for example adapt the layout from the First Posts Queue, where there is a big dark gray "Question" or "Answer" above the post title.

Comment: This seems like a good request, in fact other queues do tell you if the post is a question or an answer above the post https://imgur.com/bnOvzM4

Comment: This has already been requested earlier: [Suggested edits: Better visual indication of whether edit is to a question or an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79794/suggested-edits-better-visual-indication-of-whether-edit-is-to-a-question-or-an)

Comment: I agree with @MarkKirby. In the Close Votes queue, this question appears like [this](https://i.imgur.com/8i87YzT.png). Cute little tabs for easy switching between the question and proposed duplicate as well. I know the review queues will be getting an overhaul, but this is a good suggestion. Buuut... it *has* been suggested before. I'm going to vote to close as a dupe of what Sonic found, but I'm still tossing this an upvote.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Thanks, I did not find that question when googling - which kind of surprised me, that no one has asked for this before. So it was already a problem back in 2011 :D  Hopefully this will be addressed during the review overhaul.